# How should I store an array in Google Datastore?

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I am developing a PHP and Google Datastore based project management website, where a project can have multiple members as well. The members should be stored for a project, but I do not know, which is the best solution to do this. How can an array be stored in GDS?

Should I create a simple string, separated with ";" for example?

Or is it a better solution to make a separated Entity Kind list and store each member as a row? (as I counted it will do much more reads on the Datastore)

The number of the members is not fix, it can be from 0 to "unlimited".
I use Tom Walder's php-gdb library for GQL.

Comment: in the docs it mentions a list type but limited to a certain size. unlimited will not fit in a single entity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tom (php-gds author) here. Hope the library is working for you!

The answer is to use a "String List" - which is a specific data type in Datastore for storing arrays.

Some docs here on creating schemas
https://github.com/tomwalder/php-gds/blob/master/README.md#defining-your-model

You need 
`addStringList("members")`
Or something similar.

Are you using schemas already?

Comment: Hi Tom, thank you for your help and your code, it is working perfect :)
I'm already using schemas, and during the weekend I will try to implement the mentioned String List into my code. I think now I know how should I start with the arrays.

I will give a feedback after the test.

Comment: Hi Tom, thank you for your help, I've managed to implement the StringList to my code. It is working perfect!